# Heroku times out on redirect

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm making a simple node.js app to interact with my bookmarked links and redirect to one of them. It works well in my local server but it crashes on Heroku.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, since the logs give me two different hints:

```
2017-01-12T02:43:44.560040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-01-12T02:52:15.123679+00:00 app[web.1]: Promise Rejected: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
2017-01-12T02:52:45.101229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=pure-badlands-34207.herokuapp.com request_id=5c64483f-7fb0-49cd-ac97-37aa6b6aee57 fwd="179.155.37.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

This is my code:

```
var browserBookmarks = require('browser-bookmarks');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
   browserBookmarks.getChrome().then(function(bookmarks){
     var n = bookmarks.length;
     var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
     var url = bookmarks[ind].url;
     res.redirect(url);
   }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log("Promise Rejected: " + e);
   });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
   console.log('Shuffle App listening on port' + port);
});
```

Any work around will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The error says that the bookmark at the `ind` of `bookmarks`  doesn't exist. Hence you are getting `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`. Try `console.log(bookmarks)` . I think `bookmarks.length` is 0

Comment: Yes, the `bookmarks` object is empty, but when I run it locally `bookmarks.length` is 51 and I can access the `url` property. So the problem is why it times out. Am I not handling the promise as Heroku would expect?

Comment: `browser-bookmarks` can load the bookmarks of browsers installed on the system where the app runs. On your local machine, it loads bookmarks successfully, but on heroku, there doesn't exist any browser, hence no bookmarks. This plugin doesn't load bookmarks of the client's browser.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try hosting somewhere else. Thanks